# Rendering HTML Heading Elements in Twig

Tags: twig, html-heading

I am rendering some headings using twig and want to know if there is a better and more readable way of doing the following...

```
<{{ block.headingType }} class="measure-wide">{{ block.headingText }}</{{ block.headingType }}>
```

{{ block.headingType }} is the value of the heading selected in the editor. the values are h2, h3, h4, h5 etc.

The way the HTML headings are templated looks ugly (even though the rendering works). Is there a better way of rendering out the heading tags in twig based on the value selected?

Comment: introduce a `__toString` method in your `block`-class and u could just do `{{ block | raw }}`

Comment: Can you give me an example in a response below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a lot of headers, I'd suggest to create a class to let you handle this and add a `toString` method, which makes it easier to render the tag

```
class Heading {

    private $heading_type = 'h1';
    private $heading_text;
    private $classes = [];

    public function __construct($text) {
        $this->setHeadingText($text);
    }

    public function addClass($c) {
        if (!in_array($c, $this->classes)) $this->classes[] = $c;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHtml() {
        return new \Twig_Markup($this->__toString(), 'UTF-8');
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return '<'.$this->getHeadingType().(!empty($this->getClasses()) ? ' class="'.implode(' ',$this->getClasses()).'"':'').'>'.$this->getHeadingText().'</'.$this->getHeadingType().'>';
    }

/**============================================
                GETTERS/SETTERS
============================================**/
    public function setHeadingType($value) {
        $this->heading_type = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeadingType() {
        return $this->heading_type;
    }

    public function setHeadingText($value) {
        $this->heading_text = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeadingText() {
        return $this->heading_text;
    }

    public function getClasses() {
        return $this->classes;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
    $twig->render('template.twig', [
        'heading1' => new Heading('Title'),
        'heading2' => (new Heading('Subtitle'))->setHeadingType('h2')
                                               ->addClass('foo'),
    ]);
```

---

```
{{ heading1 | raw }} {# out: <h1>Title</h1> #}
{{ heading2 | raw }} {# out: <h2 class="foo">Subtitle</h2> #}
```

---

*edit: Added a `getHtml` which allows you to drop the raw filter e.g.*

```
{{ heading1.getHtml() }} {# out: <h1>Title</h1> #}
```